# GoogleApiClient issue: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet

Tags: java, android, google-api-client

In this class,:

```
public class Presence implements ConnectionCallbacks,
                                 OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener
```

I have the following constructor:

```
    private Presence(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;

        gApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context, this, this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        if (!gApiClient.isConnecting() && !gApiClient.isConnected())
        {
            gApiClient.connect();
        }
    } // of constructor()
```

I use it to return a `Singleton` instance:

```
public static synchronized Presence getInstance(Context context)
{
    if (presenceSingleton == null)
        presenceSingleton = new Presence(context);

    return presenceSingleton;
}
```

The `onConnected()` looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
{
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "In onConnected(), gApiClient.isConnected(): " + 
          gApiClient.isConnected());
    createLocationRequest();
    getLocation();
    getSubLocality();
} // of onConnected()
```

Based on a setting the user can make in the app, I call the following method to put the app into a so-called auto-pilot mode, where it starts tracking the user's location:

```
public void startLocationUpdates()
{
    // Prints 'false' in the logs:
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "In startLocationUpdates(), gApiClient.isConnected(): " + gApiClient.isConnected());
    Intent locationChangeIntent = new Intent(context, LocationTracker.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 188, locationChangeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Crash points to the following line: 
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(gApiClient, locationRequest, pendingIntent);
} // of startLocationUpdates()
```

In the main activity, I make an instance of the above class in the `onCreate()`:

```
public class MainClass extends AppCompatActivity implements
                                OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    ....
    ....
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getAppSettings();
        presence = Presence.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        ....
        ....
        startApp();
        ....
    }

    private void startApp()
    {
         if (pref_autoPilot)
             presence.startLocationUpdates();
    }

    ....
    ....
    ....
} // of class MainClass
```

When the user sets the auto pilot preference, the app crashes with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

at the line indicated in the above method `startLocationUpdates()`.

I read a lot of answers, but was unable to figure out a solution to this issue. Can you please point out what I am doing wrong? Is it that the `Presence` class should be in an `AppCompatActivity` or `FragmentActivity` or similar, and cannot be independent like in here? Please help me fix this nagging issue.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There are two way to call location update method. 1. if you are not getting locatoin then you have to call location updates. 2. if you are getting even you want to update then call that method in public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) method.

Comment: Thanks @Kedi! You mean I move the line `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(gApiClient, locationRequest, pendingIntent);` from `startLocationUpdates()` to `onConnected()`? Would that not always put the app in auto-pilot mode?

Comment: you should call presence.startLocationUpdates(); this method from onConnected() method. and check if your location is null then and then it will call. Try it once

Comment: @Kedi, did that, and the exception is gone. Thanks a ton! If you can make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `presence.startLocationUpdates();` this method from `onConnected()` method. And check the condition befor calling, if your location is null. Before the connection happend of GoogleApiClient you can;t update location.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the simple guidelines at [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).
I think you missed the following part:

```
protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
```

In your `MainActivity` you need to call `connect` and `disconnect` when required (in other words, when so called *auto-pilot mode* is on)

Comment: Thanks @Rehan, but the `Presence` class `extends` 'nothing'. In the `MainClass`, I get its Singleton and that should do it, right? I am doing the `disconnect()` in `MainClass`'s `onStop()`...

Comment: @NarayanaJ I don't think Singleton class has to handle everything for itself. Singleton pattern just make sure the single instance of that class. Secondly, you won't be able to use this client like this if you do not connect and disconnect it properly!

Comment: Agreed, @Rehan; I am disconnecting it manually from `MainClass`'s `onDestroy()`

Answer (score 0):

> You should instantiate a client object in your Activity's onCreate(Bundle) method and then call connect() in onStart() and disconnect() in onStop(), regardless of the state.

Comment: Thanks @mdDroid, but the `Presence` class, `extends` 'nothing'. In the `MainClass`, I get its Singleton and that should do it, right? I am doing the `disconnect()` in `MainClass`'s `onStop()`...

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, @Kedi...

> Can you please point out what I am doing wrong?

`gApiClient.connect()` was not being called in the right place. Please see the accepted answer.

> Is it that the `Presence` class should be in an `AppCompatActivity` or `FragmentActivity` or similar, and cannot be independent like in here?

It *can* be an independent class

Thanks every one for your kind help.